# PostgreSQL psql: error: falló la conexión al servidor en el socket «/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432»: No existe el fichero o el directorio

Tags: postgresql

A continuación voy a detallar mi problema a ver si me pueden ayudar.
Todo empezó cuando traté de ejecutar

```
psql capital < capital.psql
```

y me dió

```
psql: error: falló la conexión al servidor en el socket «/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432»: No existe el fichero o el directorio
    ¿Está el servidor en ejecución localmente y aceptando conexiones en ese socket?
```

Entonces lo que intenté fue reiniciar el servidor

```
systemctl restart postgresql.service
```

Lo cual escupió éste error

```
Job for postgresql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status postgresql.service" and "journalctl -xeu postgresql.service" for details.
```

Acá en éste link dejo lo que dió el Status y el journal
https://pastebin.com/QtXidWfw
Viendo todo ésto, mi paso siguiente fue intentar ejecutar `su - postgres -c "initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'"`
Como el usuario postgres no tiene contraseña, debería funcionar, pero me da fallo en la autenticación.
Luego fuí al /etc/shadow y cambié `postgres:!#:19407::::::` por `postgres::19407::::::` y en /etc/passwd `postgres:x:961:961:PostgreSQL user:/var/lib/postgres:/bin/bash`, por `postgres::961:961:PostgreSQL user:/var/lib/postgres:/bin/bash` y tampoco anduvo.
Por último traté desinstalando y volviendo a instalar postgres, pero el problema persiste. (https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1E70BDD4C8FF473597EC43642B18C51D@miportalxp sugirió eso pero además /etc/init.d no existe en mi sistema de archivos)
Qué hago?
Si me pueden ayudar se agradece
Saludos
Jenifer
P.D.: Estoy usando PostgreSQL 15 en Linux Manjaro 22

Answer (score 0):

con el comando este creaste un nuevo cluster: `su - postgres -c "initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'"` , una pregunta: ¿Como lo instalaste, me refiero al PostgreSQL?

Comment: sudo pacman -S postgresql
Así lo instalé las dos veces y su - postgres -c "initdb --locale en_US.UTF-8 -D '/var/lib/postgres/data'"  asumo que no hizo nada porque da error de autenticación